# Running Time Complexity for double input

Tags: time-complexity, exponential

Suppose you have an algorithm which for inputs of size n=1000 runs in exactly 1 second on your computer. What would be the best guess for how long the algorithm will take to run on inputs of size n=2000, if the time complexity of the algorithm would be T(n)= Θ(2^n)?

Similarly for Θ(nlogn), when the input is doubled, I know that it is between 2 sec (Θ(n)), and 4 sec (Θ(n^2)), but is there a way to be more precise?

In general, if it would be Θ(n^2), I can deduct mathematically that for double n, the time complexity would be 4 sec, for Θ(n) it woube be 2 sec and for Θ(n^3) 8 sec. But the above problems confuses me.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the runtime of the first function is O(2^n), if you go from n=1000 to n=2000, your runtime is multiplied by... 2^1000. Yikes.

For your second question, yes, the time is multiplied by 2log(2). This logic, as you can see, does not extrapolate to *any* runtime, but in this case it works.